# Trying to do this homework assignment but I keep getting a compilation error

Tags: c++

This is only the first part of my homework, I've fixed all the other compilation errors but I keep getting this error, theres five.

```
1>\takehome\main.cpp(39) : error C2065: 'j' : undeclared identifier
1>\takehome\main.cpp(44) : error C2065: 'j' : undeclared identifier
\takehome\main.cpp(45) : error C2065: 'j' : undeclared identifier
\takehome\main.cpp(76) : error C2065: 'j' : undeclared identifier
\takehome\main.cpp(80) : error C2065: 'j' : undeclared identifier
```

I've tried doing everything with it, but I'm probably doing something wrong..obviously I am. I could use some help if you don't mind :). Btw, in case anyone was wondering, doing simpletron.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int memory[100]; //Making it 100, since simpletron contains a 100 word mem.

 int operation; //taking the rest of these variables straight out of the book seeing as how they were italisized.

 int operand;

 int accum = 0; // the special register is starting at 0

 int position = 0; //making the starting position to be 0.

 for ( int j = 0; j < 100; j++ ) //Simply stating that for int j is = to 0, j must be less than 100 because that is the memory limit, and for every pass-through, increment j.

  memory[j] = 0;


 // This is for part a, it will take in positive variables in a sent-controlled loop and compute + print their sum. These are random variables.
 memory [0] = 2942;

 memory [1] = 2342;

 memory [2] = 3523;

 memory [3] = 2031;

 memory [4] = 5000;

 memory [5] = 8080;

 memory [6] = 3425;

 j = 0; //Makes the variable j start at 0.

 while ( true )
 {

  memory[ j ]%100 = operand; // Finds the op codes from the limit on the memory (100)
  memory[ j ]%100 = operation;

  //using a switch loop to set up the loops for the cases
  switch ( operation ){
   case 1: //reads a variable into a word from loc.
    cout <<"\n Input a positive variable:  ";
    cin >> memory[ operand ]; break;

   case 2: // takes a word from location
    cout << "\n\nThe content at location " << operand << "is " << memory[operand]; break;

   case 3:// loads
    accum = memory[ operand ]; break;

   case 4: //stores
    memory[ operand ] = accum; break;

   case 5: //adds
    accum = accum + memory[ operand ]; break;


   case 6: // subtracts
    accum = accum - memory[ operand ]; break;

   case 7: //divides
    accum = accum / (memory[ operand ]); break;

   case 8: // multiplies
    accum = accum*memory [ operand ]; break;

   case 9: // Branches to location
    j = -1; break;

   case 10: //branches if acc. is < 0
    if (accum < 0)
    j = 5; break;

   case 11: //branches if acc = 0
    if (accum == 0); break;

   case 12: // Program ends
    exit(0); break;
 }
 j++;
 }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @pickypg Please don't add homework tag to questions, it is currently blacklisted (read the tag description).

Comment: @Tim I rolled back the change, which was following the tag's description of not removing unless the question needed cleanup. Though to be fair, I had still been adding it to some new questions.

Comment: @Josh: You should strive to keep indentation consistent. You may be surprised how many errors can be avoided by correct indentation simply because you see the errors when you indent, such as variables declared in the wrong scope as the case is here. :)

Answer (score 18):

Declare "j" outside the "for" loop. When you declare it *inside* the loop header, it's local to the loop's block and not visible outside it.

Answer (score 11):

When you declare a variable inside of a `for` statement, that variable is only in scope for the body of the `for` loop, e.g.

```
for ( int j = 0; j < 100; j++ ) 
{
  // j is defined in here
}

// But j is undefined out here
```

Answer (score 3):

You are setting `j = 0` without declaring it like `int j = 0`.

You did it inside the `for` loop but its local scope lasts just for the body of the loop..

Answer (score 2):

When you have something like

```
for ( int i = 0; i < k; ++i )
{ 
// stuff 
}
```

`i` is only available in the scope of the `for` loop, so if you do something like this:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < k; ++i )
{ 
// stuff 
}
cout << i;
```

You get a compilation error at `cout << i;`, because `i` no longer exists after the `for` loop finished.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, the scope of a variable declared in a for loop is the loop. So when you say:

```
for ( int j = 0; j < 100; j++ ) {
    // j only exists here (and in the for statement itself)
}
```

The variable j only exists in the body of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The variable j is local to the for loop.  You need to increase its scope, by doing something like this:

```
int j;
for(j = 0; j < 100; ++j)
```

or redeclare it later:

```
for(int j=0; j<100; ++j)
...
...
int j = 0;
while(true) 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`j` exists only in the for loop, that is in instruction

```
for ( int j = 0; j < 100; j++ ) //Simply stating that for int j is = to 0, j must be less than 100 because that is the memory limit, and for every pass-through, increment j.
    memory[j] = 0;
```

You should have written

```
int j;
for(j=0;j<100;j++)
...
```